# How can I build a redstone-powered vehicle?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I tried to build a redstone vehicle in Minecraft (vanilla), but my attempts proved futile. I tried to build it using pistons, wire and some pushable blocks, but it didn't work, because the wire breaks when pushed. Also, when I used redstone blocks right in front of the pistons, they haven't extended. Any idea for a redstone-using vehicle, on unmodded Minecraft?

Comment: Redstone wire vreaks when oushed by pistons. Some nice machines made with slime blocks, sticky pistons and redstone block can work as a redstone car. Browse through youtube, there are some machines like these.

Comment: I knew the wire breaks when pushed. That's why I need help. @spund3

Comment: A redstone vehicle using redstone wires is impossible. You can do one with slime blocks, sticky pistons and redstone blocks.

Comment: Ok. I'll give it a shot. @spund3

Comment: Try the following link, is the thing you need. https://youtu.be/Qa3paQM67YU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need slime blocks. They not only prevent fall damage and a trampoline effect, it also gets attatched to blocks so when the block is moved with s piston, the slime block moves with it depending on what block it's next to. This is very useful for cars. Here's an example of a slime block car:

You need:

- Pistons
- Sticky Pistons
- Redstone Blocks
- **Slime Blocks**

Use these to build your slime block car. Since redstone falls of a moved block, use slime blocks and redstone blocks instead of dust!